# Name of backquote character in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In System.Windows.Forms.Keys, what is the name of the backquote (`) character? Is backquote not its proper name, or is it just a quirk of VS?

Or, otherwise, what is its numeric value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `KeyValue` for the character is `223`. To check, you can just handle a textbox's keydown event like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
        MessageBox.Show(e.KeyValue.ToString())
End Sub
```

and press the (`) key. If you want to compare the `KeyData`, it's under `Keys.Oem8`.

Edit - As noted in the comments, the `KeyValue` may change across systems. The enumeration `Keys.Oem8` should handle this, so this would be the preferred method of checking if the key is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll just note for anyone else who may see this, mine has a value of 192, so you may want to check it on your own system.

Comment: @wyatt - Good point. It's probably best to use the `Keys.Oem8` as the check as that should internally map to whatever `KeyValue` it is on your system.

Comment: You're right, too. I must have skimmed a bit too quickly reading your message, missed that.